# Driver couldn't initialize via BrowserStack running on Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins-plugins, browserstack

I tried to setup Jenkins job to run tests using BrowserStack. Locally, tests go fine, driver initialized, session is created ad tests started to run with '   `"browserstack.local": true`. In Jenkins there is a plugin installed. But below error exist `com.browserstack.local.LocalException: Error trying to download BrowserStackLocal binary` even if BrowserStack Local is uncheked in Jenkins.

If locally I set `"browserstack.local": false` then below errors exist
`org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to hub-cloud.browserstack.com/`

Once locally `"browserstack.local": false` is setted then error is pointing to below line
 `driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), capabilities)`

I expected that via Jenkins connection to BrowserStack should be done as locally.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to run the tests on BrowserStack earlier from your network OR You are trying to set up a new framework/tests?

Could you share more details about the issue you are facing?

- What is your test setup? What is the language/framework? How are the capabilities set?
- Share the complete error logs. Also, share the Jenkins build setup screenshot and what type of Jenkins project is it (*Freestyle, Pipeline, Folder, etc*)?

The error- '*Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to hub-cloud.browserstack.com*' suggests that the request is not able to reach BrowserStack HUB. If you are behind a proxy/firewall, please ensure that valid proxy details are passed to the test. Review [this document](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/java#proxy).

For Jenkins setup, ensure you are following [the official BrowserStack document](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/jenkins). Do review these videos for your reference as well- [VID_1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JRXS4bSzPiMApIseetTkgadnctj2nMBG) , [VID_2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12xpW54Ax2Sa4aqJRXZ8rk8haBBiIauFa)

Answer (score 0):

I added `"browserstack.localIdentifier"` capability and below system properties `"http.proxyHost"`, `"http.proxyPort"`